# Grease pencil stroke is very thick but can't find adjustment

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I'm a new user of blender. I'm importing a svg file with python and setting the material with python as well.

However, somewhere in the process the thickness is getting ruined.

svg looks nice without stroke:
[image]

However, if I add the stroke it is WAY to thick:

[image]

Where do you think there is a messed up setting?
I've looked everywhere without luck.

I've also made a simple circle with python (not an imported svg) and the stroke looks fine and not bloated like the example I post, so I'm extra puzzled and would love your input on this.

edit//
this [here](https://we.tl/t-Xh2V1OKCbR) is the file. And here are the stroke settings
the strokes settings:

[image]

edit2// I found out there error happens when I swap the default material out with a blank new one... what gives?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

In this thread we touched quite a few parameters that influence stroke thickness, but there is one more: the `pressure` factor in stroke points. With this attribute the thickness can vary along the stroke, e.g. when you draw with a pressure sensitive tablet.

Normally this `pressure` factor is between 0.0 and 1.0. But it *can* be higher. And somehow all the points in your file had a whopping pressure of **100.0**. So all the other settings were multiplied by a factor 100 (and made hardly sense as a result).

I don't know where that happened in your workflow, but when it's something clearly reproducable, you could file a bug report.

With this snippet you can set the stroke point pressure to a normal value:

```
import bpy

# Loop all Grease Pencil objects
for gpd in bpy.data.grease_pencils:
    # Loop all layers
    for gpl in gpd.layers:
        gpf = gpl.active_frame
        # Loop all strokes in active frame
        for gps in gpf.strokes:
            # You can set the stroke width here to your liking
            gps.line_width = 3
            # Loop all points in stroke
            for p in gps.points:
                # Adjust thickness of this point,
                # by setting the pressure to the default 1.0.
                p.pressure = 1.0
```

After that the other settings are far more predictable.

**Original answer**

In the stroke setting, change Stroke Thickness from `Screen Space` into `World Space` and you are probably good to go.

See the [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/strokes.html) explaining the difference. I don't fully grasp why the 'Screen Space' setting exists, to be honest. Perhaps it's a legacy thing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm sure the screen space is what I need for the project, so I would love to make it work. I updated with question - I found out the problem happens when adding a blank new material.

Comment: Phew! You've just rescued me from a blunder in another answer. I was looking for this setting everywhere. If the thickness of a stroke is in World Space, then, in perspective, it will be thinner the farther away it is from the viewpoint. This is often [_not_  what's wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhm1h.png), e.g. for technical illustration, or toon ink'n'paint. If the thickness is in Screen Space, then it will be constant.. unaffected by the perspective transform.

Comment: @RobinBetts I have different size thickness even though all objects are in `screen space` and are the same distance. I uploaded a file

Comment: This happens by using `obj.data.stroke_thickness_space = 'SCREENSPACE'` before `stroke.line_width  = value`.. But somehow this does not apply to the imported svg.

Comment: Hi, @nammerkage .. I was only referring to the UI, in this case, sorry.. no great shakes with bpy... but  I would still take a look.. don't see the file?

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts it's here https://we.tl/t-qrk2J1rgVV I would love your view on it. One circle is set with `stroke.line_width  = 5` and another at value `10`. However, I can't set it low enough for the imported svg t obe visable

Comment: @nammerkage  [This](https://imgur.com/a/N7D6JWa) is as far as I've got. Uncomfortable posting as answer, since I don't fully understand the logic, and the docs aren't helping me very much.

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you! Setting negative stroke thickness will be helpful, I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: There was an other thing going on, an unusal `pressure` value in the stroke points. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for enlightening me on the obvious value of Screen Space. We've learned from each other, it seems!

Comment: @SietseBrouwer `pressure factor` was the error. THANK YOU